# Not able to make an Azure app as member of an Azure Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to add an Azure app as member of the Azure Group. I am owner of the Group but when I click on Add-->Member , it only lists individual users and there is no option for adding an app:-

[image]

I am not trying to provide access to the SG so it can access the app (for that I will have to go to the specific app page) rather I am trying to make the app as the 'member' of an Azure group that I already own. But I just don't see an option for doing that.

Comment: It should work, can you see the app in the `Enterprise applications`(search for its name with the application type `All applications`)? In other words, do you have permission to list the apps?

Comment: yes I can list enterprise apps there, but I don't see this particular app (it's a data factory v2). But since I am able to see some apps, it means I do have permission to list apps , but as you can see from add members screenshot, it is only allowing me to add users and not apps.

Comment: I just verified that even if the prompt says 'User' , I am able to type name of other apps (such as git) and it shows up, but this one particular app (ADF v2) I just don't see there

Comment: Navigate to your ADF v2 in the portal -> `Properties` -> check the `Managed Identity Application ID ` and tenant id, make sure you in the correct tenant, and search for the `Application ID` in the `Enterprise applications`. Could you find it?

Comment: I confirmed I am in the correct tenant -- and yes if I search the application in Enterprise application, I do find that specific data factory. Now, back to the real question, how do I add this app to the azure group which is in the same tenant? If I just specify this application id in add user option for the group, it says not found, it's clearly requiring some sort of email format I think, either associated with app or a user.

Comment: Is your group a security group or an office group? Are you sure you can see other service principals in the `Add members` page?

Comment: @JoyWang this is an Office group -- when I created the group, 'Group type' was pre-filled with 'Office 365' and was not selectable. Yes, I can see individual user ids, in add members, in fact I have added a dozen users as a member to the group already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your group is an `Office` group, it does not support to add the [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object) as a member(i.e. the MSI of your datafactory, which is essentially a service principal created by azure automatically in general, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#generate-managed-identity)).

If you want to add the service principal to the group, you need to use the `Security` group, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal).

If your `User type` is `member`, but you are not able to create the `Security` group, the `UsersPermissionToCreateGroupsEnabled` setting should be set with `false` in your Azure AD tenant.

See [To restrict the default permissions for member users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#to-restrict-the-default-permissions-for-member-users):

[image]

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-settings-cmdlets).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command first from powershell to create the managed identity

`Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -Name <dataFactoryName> -Location <region>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity

Comment: I see there is already a managed identity (we didn't create it) for the data factory, looks like it got auto-created by azure, because we didn't create it for sure. So, in the properties section I see 3 values-- Managed Identity Object ID , Managed Identity Tenant , Managed Identity Application ID. The question is , just with these values (these are GUIDs) how do I add this data factory as the member of the Azure group? Clearly if I just try to add these guids , it wont accept.